# extract sub string from column in dataframe, iteratively

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, extract

I have a dataframe that contains multiple columns. The column 'group_email" contains multiple parts of data that's relevant, and I want to extract a specific subtring from the 'group_email' column and create a new column from it for each row. However, there are multiple patterns the email follows so I have to first check which sub string the email starts with to know which regex pattern to use.

```
for ind in group_member_df.index:  
        if(group_member_df['group_email'][ind].startswith("gcp") is True):
            group_member_df['group_code'][ind] = (group_member_df['group_email'][ind].str.extract('(?:prod-)(.*)-'))
            
        elif(group_member_df['group_email'][ind].startswith("irm") is True):
            group_member_df['group_code'][ind] = (group_member_df['group_email'][ind].str.extract('^(?:[^-]*\-){6}([^.]*)'))
            
        else:
            group_member_df['group_code'][ind] = '0'
```

I have this logic, where i iterate through each row in the dataframe, see if the email starts with 'gcp' or 'irm' if one of those, I want to extract from the group_email using a specific regex, if neither just set the group_code to 0.

However i'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "directory.py", line 225, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "directory.py", line 202, in main
    group_member_df['group_code'][ind] = (group_member_df['group_email'][ind].str.extract('(?:prod-)(.*)-'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

When trying to call .str.extract... on the specific index of the dataframe. What would be the correct way of doing this?
Here is raw data from the dataframe that I want to parse from:

```
,group_kind,group_id,group_etag,group_email,group_description,group_directMembersCount,group_name,kind,etag,id,email,role,type,status
    0,admin#directory#group,037m2jsg1zte0ru,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/H_trseaMC0ciMbbaeYJ5C7J1vdU""",gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups@im.com,This is created for taxonomy,7,gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups,admin#directory#member,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/XprY4N1E2ZREZ95Av98__pbQZXg""",115332437364675590394,astronomer@irm-eap-edp-core-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com,MEMBER,USER,ACTIVE
    1,admin#directory#group,037m2jsg1zte0ru,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/H_trseaMC0ciMbbaeYJ5C7J1vdU""",gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups@im.com,This is created for taxonomy,7,gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups,admin#directory#member,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/WDJKr0BpbrpusytGd_HBA_wVzRQ""",102931703871297935722,hema.sundarreddy.contr@im.com,MEMBER,USER,ACTIVE
    2,admin#directory#group,037m2jsg1zte0ru,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/H_trseaMC0ciMbbaeYJ5C7J1vdU""",gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups@im.com,This is created for taxonomy,7,gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups,admin#directory#member,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/1z_mHHk4rwh93nZf55UPPWGjFyc""",111625551155802089398,irm-eap-edp-core-prod@appspot.gserviceaccount.com,MEMBER,USER,
    3,admin#directory#group,037m2jsg1zte0ru,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/H_trseaMC0ciMbbaeYJ5C7J1vdU""",gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups@im.com,This is created for taxonomy,7,gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups,admin#directory#member,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/Q7YEC8F_JeB1jKBsNam3u2fiF1o""",107499294203545833692,jarrett.garcia@im.com,OWNER,USER,ACTIVE
    4,admin#directory#group,037m2jsg1zte0ru,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/H_trseaMC0ciMbbaeYJ5C7J1vdU""",gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups@im.com,This is created for taxonomy,7,gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups,admin#directory#member,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/z5Cw_9BaO6gEOiiiX2k9HXfW5uc""",102874697335989237851,shalini.rajamani@im.com,MEMBER,USER,ACTIVE
    5,admin#directory#group,037m2jsg1zte0ru,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/H_trseaMC0ciMbbaeYJ5C7J1vdU""",gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups@im.com,This is created for taxonomy,7,gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups,admin#directory#member,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/G8PLD_6sZpjHCS44h6_9rRXIt0I""",103243562666022054078,suraj.angadi.contr@im.com,MEMBER,USER,ACTIVE
    6,admin#directory#group,037m2jsg1zte0ru,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/H_trseaMC0ciMbbaeYJ5C7J1vdU""",gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups@im.com,This is created for taxonomy,7,gcp-edp-platform-dgov-prod-aadrpt-allsensitive.groups,admin#directory#member,"""ncll-7bPS7lrDES-QUXBlfs2Pot1Y168LPxnrGE6FJU/UU6ouU-RZwaU6rXCFtRmUm0Tjdk""",103099940548030708420,svc.appscripts@im.com,MANAGER,USER,ACTIVE
```

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example and the matching expected output

Answer (score 0):

`.str.extract()` is a pandas.Series method while
`group_member_df['group_email'][ind]` is a string so it doesn't have the `extract()` method.

I would try something like

```
prefix_dict = {"gcp":'(?:prod-)(.*)-',"irm":'^(?:[^-]*\-){6}([^.]*)'}
res={}
for prefix in prefix_dict.keys():
    mask = group_member_df.loc[:,'group_email'].str.startswith("gcp")
    reg = prefix_dict[prefix]
    res[prefix] = (group_member_df.loc[mask, 'group_email'].str.extract(reg))
```

Note that `extract()` returns a pandas DataFrame so cannot be directly inserted back into `group_member_df` without further processing. Here I collect it into a dict to allow such processing.

I use the mask because vector functions are faster then iterating over rows or columns.